# ListView Style Trigger affecting one control and not another

Tags: wpf, listview, foreground

I have a ListView control with a list of system messages in it, and a corresponding "action" button that will help my user resolve the message:

[image: Example of problem]

If the message is an error message, I want the Foreground of the text and the action button (the [more...] part) to turn red. As you can see, it's not doing that.

I'm using a Style.Trigger bound to the message data's Severity to set the Foreground. This works fine for the TextBlock in the DataTemplate, but fails to affect the Button in that Template. My XAML looks like this:

```
   <ListView x:Name="ImageCenterStatus" Background="{DynamicResource SC.ControlBrush}" Margin="10,22,10,0"  FontSize="12" Grid.Column="1" ClipToBounds="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseUp] = [Action DoStatusAction($dataContext)]" Text="{Binding Path=DisplayedMessage}"/>
                        <Button x:Name="ActionButton" Content="{Binding Path=DisplayedActionLabel}" FontSize="12" cal:Message.Attach="DoStatusAction($dataContext)" Style="{DynamicResource SC.ActionButtonHack}"></Button>
                    </WrapPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Severity}" Value="Warning">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFCE7A16"  />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Severity}" Value="Error">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFD13636"  />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
```

The Button has its own Style, SC.ActionButtonHack, but I am very careful not to override the Foreground anywhere that style:

```
            <Style x:Key="SC.ActionButtonHack" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Why does the TextBlock in the DataTemplate respond to the Foreground change in the Trigger, but not the Button?
What do I need to do to get the button to respect the Foreground change?

Comment: What on earth is your `SC.ActionButtonHack Style` for?

Comment: For testing purposes. I have a much more involved style, but I was stripping it down to keep this post short.

Comment: That seems fair enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind `TextElement.Foreground` of ContentPresenter to `ListViewItem's foreground` to get it work:

```
<Style x:Key="SC.ActionButtonHack" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
       <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
              <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                TextElement.Foreground="{Binding Foreground, 
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                  AncestorType=ListViewItem}}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0"/>
          </ControlTemplate>
       </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

OR

Either bind it on Button itself:

```
<Button x:Name="ActionButton"
        Foreground="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                         Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListViewItem}}"
        Content="{Binding Path=Name}" FontSize="12"
        Style="{DynamicResource SC.ActionButtonHack}"/>
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you so much. So... why did the style trigger work for the TextBlock but not the Button?

Comment: If you look at default controlTemplate of button, you will find that its has default value set for foreground property in its template which has higher precedence than property value inheritance that's why it does not inherit from its parent ListViewItem. Read more about DP value precedence order [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: But am I not overriding the default ControlTemplate in my style? How could the default still be affecting this?